# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools_rust' when installing packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to install paramiko using pip package on centos7 OS and getting issues like as below and installed python3 with below command

```
yum install -y python3
```

```
[root@test ~]# pip3 install paramiko
WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `pip3 install --user` instead.
Collecting paramiko
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/04/e5/39ec73dd4a8769d6759b8d6c60a1b2c9337f585407c2ae8bfb8ccb734278/paramiko-2.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cryptography>=2.5 (from paramiko)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/51/05/bb2b681f6a77276fc423d04187c39dafdb65b799c8d87b62ca82659f9ead/cryptography-37.0.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    
            =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE==========================
            If you are seeing an error here please try the following to
            successfully install cryptography:
    
            Upgrade to the latest pip and try again. This will fix errors for most
            users. See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip
            =============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE==========================
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-ccbam6fs/cryptography/setup.py", line 14, in <module>
        from setuptools_rust import RustExtension
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools_rust'
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ccbam6fs/cryptography/
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ModuleNotFoundError%3A+No+module+named+setuptools_rust

Answer (score 0):

Just need to Upgrade pip package

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

or

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```